# Samsung S4 action bar gets drawables from drawable-normal-mdpi

Tags: android, android-actionbar, screen-resolution, samsung-mobile

For some reason, the action bar items looked small on S4.
On close examination, it seems that, instead of using drawable-xxhdpi, Android is using drawable-normal-mdpi.

Any help in evaluating this mess that is Android in general, would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't noticed any definition of xxhdpi on official documentation, however make sure you are providing images with same name to that folder, but from personal experience it works when i provide xhdpi

Comment: I do provide xhdpi. It is pretty weird though, that the normal-mdpi folder is selected. It should not fit size or resolution for S4... Interestingly enough, this happens in the action bar only, as far as I can tell - I will try on actual layout as well as soon as I have the chance.